# Closest in if statement and parse data in function loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code from menu:

```html
<ul id="sidebarMenu" class="nav nav-sidebar" data-nav-type="accordion">
    <li class="nav-item nav-item-submenu nav-item-expanded nav-item-open">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fad fa-user-tie fa-fw mr-2"></i>Webadmin</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-group-sub">
            <li class="nav-item nav-item-submenu nav-item-expanded nav-item-open"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-abacus mr-2"></i>tester</a>
                <ul class="nav nav-group-sub">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-submenu nav-item-expanded nav-item-open">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-abacus mr-2"></i>tester 2</a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-group-sub">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="/webadmin/config" class="nav-link active"><i class="fad fa-cogs fa-fw mr-2"></i>Site instellingen</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/webadmin/configMenu" class="nav-link "><i class="fad fa-list fa-fw mr-2"></i>Menu aanpassen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I want is add a class 'nav-item-expanded nav-item-open' on al related li with class nav-item-submenu.

So if the user is an a page that the menu collapse automatically the sub menus until the link

I have the next code:

This works. But its limited on my script this wil go back for 5 subs. But if the user want to use by example 6 menus the script fails. Sorry for my bad writing: D

```js
$('.nav-item > a.active')
    .closest('.nav-item-submenu')
    .addClass('nav-item-expanded nav-item-open')
    .parent()
    .closest('.nav-item-submenu')
    .addClass('nav-item-expanded nav-item-open')
    .parent()
    .closest('.nav-item-submenu')
    .addClass('nav-item-expanded nav-item-open')
    .parent()
    .closest('.nav-item-submenu')
    .addClass('nav-item-expanded nav-item-open')
    .parent()
    .closest('.nav-item-submenu')
    .addClass('nav-item-expanded nav-item-open')
```

how can I simplify this code?

Example that I have tried:

```js
var test = function(data = '') {
    if (data === '') {
        data = $('.nav-item > a.active').closest('.nav-item-submenu');
    } else {
        data = data.parent().closest('nav-item-submenu');
    }

    if (data.length > 0) {
        data.addClass('nav-item-expanded nav-item-open');
        test(data);
    }
};
```

but that's not working.

Comment: You should provide an HTML example that the code should work on.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do exactly? Is it supposed to add the same class to *all* ancestors that match a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.parentsUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/) to simplify this. It returns all ancestors up to a point and can filter them. It takes two parameters:

1. Selector for the final ancestor to stop at.
2. Selector to filter the ancestors by.

This is almost the opposite of [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) which will traverse descendants instead. However, `.find()` will always work at any depth, it does not have a stop conditions like `.parentsUntil()`.

A single call to `.parentsUntil('#sidebarMenu', '.nav-item-submenu')` will return all ancestor elements that you want - the `.nav-item-submenu` ones. At that point, you can add the classes you want or manipulate them further, if needed.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {

  $('.nav-item > a.active')
    .parentsUntil('#sidebarMenu', '.nav-item-submenu')
    .addClass('nav-item-expanded nav-item-open');
})
```

```css
.nav-item-submenu {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.nav-item-expanded {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.nav-item-open {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sidebarMenu" class="nav nav-sidebar" data-nav-type="accordion">
    <li class="nav-item nav-item-submenu">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">A</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-group-sub">
            <li class="nav-item nav-item-submenu"><a href="#" class="nav-link">B1</a>
                <ul class="nav nav-group-sub">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">C</a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-group-sub">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link active">D</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link ">B2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<button>Click me</button>
```